# Laravel 5 pagination with orderBy

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent, laravel-5

I have been trying to paginate Eloquent result in laravel 5. But I'm facing a problem.

Following code works

```
$brand = $this->brand->select('id', 'label', 'slug', 'logo', 'banner_image', \DB::raw('CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN "Disabled" else "Enabled" END as status'));

    if($filter) {
        $brand = $brand->where('label', '=', $filter);
    }

    return  $brand->paginate($show);
```

But when I try to order the result, it doesnt work

```
    $brand = $this->brand->select('id', 'label', 'slug', 'logo', 'banner_image', \DB::raw('CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN "Disabled" else "Enabled" END as status'));

    if($filter) {
        $brand = $brand->where('label', '=', $filter);
    }

    return  $brand->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate($show);
```

It throws me **Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception**. How to fix this?

Note : $this->brand holds the instance of Brand Model

Comment: You are trying to cast a View object to a string that's why you are getting this error. Please do a `dd()` and on the returned value and also post your view code please.

Comment: Thanks @akad0. Yes, it seems like I have made a mistake in manipulating the details I receive from model. Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like...

```
$data = brand->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate($show);
return View::make('your_view')->with($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This Error can occur in Following situations:

Situation 1: Trying to print out a value in an array.

Answer 1: Try printing out the array. Are you sure it's an array? I've gotten this error when it was an object instead of an array. Try doing a print_r and seeing what you get.

Situation 2: You have this associated array like this:

```
Array
    (
        [post_id] => 65
        [post_text] => Multiple Images!
        [created_at] => 2014-10-23 09:16:46
        [updated_on] => 
        [post_category] => stdClass Object
            (
                [category_label] => Help Wanted
                [category_code] => help_wanted
            )

        [employee_full_name] => Sam Jones
        [employee_pic] => /images/employee-image-placeholder.png
        [employee_email] => jon@gmail.com
        [post_images] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [image_path] => 9452photo_2.JPG
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [image_path] => 8031photo_3.JPG
                    )

            )

    )
```

When you try to access post_images array directly within a View, it throws an error. No. Matter. What. You. Do.

Answer 2: Check in all the places where you are calling the View. What happened here is that I was trying to access the same view somewhere else in an area where I wasn't giving the post_images array. Took FOREVER to figure out.